# JDOM2, xmlns (xsd) c'ant change or remove from XML document

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jdom-2

I dont have the xsd file of an xml document, so I must change to default xmlns "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" to pars the XML elements but there is a problem to do it, when I change xmlns  attribute of root element (myroot)  another attribute (xmlns) is created  in the child element (data) with the value "myxsd.xsd". 
I want to ignore or change the value of xmlns ( myxsd.xsd ) to parse the document correctly.

My XML Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<myroot xmlns="myxsd.xsd" class="15">
    <data att1="all" att2="actual">
        <myobject patt1="patt1_value" patt2="patt2_value" patt3="patt3_value">
            <p name="p1">page1</p>
            <p name="p2">page1</p>
            <p name="p3">page1</p>
            <p name="p4">page4</p>
        </myobject>
    </data>
</myroot>
```

My XML Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myroot xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" class="15">
  <data xmlns="myxsd.xsd" att1="all" att2="actual">
    <myobject patt1="patt1_value" patt2="patt2_value" patt3="patt3_value">
      <p name="p1">page1</p>
      <p name="p2">page1</p>
      <p name="p3">page1</p>
      <p name="p4">page4</p>
    </myobject>
  </data>
</myroot>
```

My Code:

```
public void Edit_file() throws JDOMException, IOException {

    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("C:\\small_test.xml");

    SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document document = builder.build(in);

    // getting the root element
    Element root = document.getRootElement();
    Namespace tempNamespace = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
    root.setNamespace(tempNamespace);


    // iterating over the children
    List<Element> data = root.getChildren("data");

    for (Element element : data) {

        Attribute id = element.getAttribute("att1");
        id.setValue("New value");
    }
    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();

    xmlOutput.setFormat(Format.getPrettyFormat());
    xmlOutput.output(document, System.out);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why you want to move the elements into a different namespace (especially into the namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, which is not intended for this purpose), but if you want to do it, you must change all the elements, not just the outermost one. Although the namespace declaration is only present on the outermost element, it has the effect of putting all the elements in this namespace, and they will remain in that namespace unless you change them.

Comment: I want to remove the attribute xmlns from the input XML file, but I don't know how do it.

Comment: Then the first thing you need to understand is the effect of xmlns attributes in the source XML on the names and other properties of nodes in the JDOM representation of the parsed XML. Sorry if I failed to explain that. I'll try again: an xmlns attribute on the outermost element changes the namespace URI of every element in the tree, and to get rid of the namespace, you need to change the name of every element.